# Problem with XLS files with R's package readxl

Tags: r, excel, readxl

I need to read a XLS file in R, but I'm having a problem regarding the way my file is generated and the R function readxl. I *do not* have this issue with Python, and this is my hope that it's possible to solve this problem inside R.

An application we use at my company exports reports in XLS format (not XLSX). This report is generated daily. What I need is to sum the total value of the rows in each file, in order to create a new report containing each day followed by this total value.

When I try to read these files in R using the readxl package, the program returns this error:

```
Erro: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Location 5 doesn't exist.
i There are only 0 columns.
Run rlang::last_error() to see where the error occurred.
```

Now, the weird thing is that, when I open the XLS file on Excel **before** running my script, R is able to run properly.

I guesses this was an error caused by something like the file only being completed when I open it... but the same python script *does* give me the correct result.

I am now assuming this is a bug in the readxl package. Is there another package I could use to run XLS (and not XLSX)? One that does not depend on Java installed on my computer, I mean.

my readxl script:

```
if (!require("readxl")) {install.packages("readxl"); library("readxl")}

"%,%" <- function(x,y) paste0(x,"\\",y)

year = "2021"
month = "Aug"


column = 5 # VL_COVAR

path <- "F:\\variancia" %,% year %,% month

tiposDF = c("date","numeric","list","numeric","numeric","numeric","list")

file.names <- dir(path, pattern =".xls")

vari <- c()
for (i in 1:length(file.names)){
  
  file <- paste(path,sep="\\",file.names[i])
  print(paste("Reading ", file))
  
 dados <- read_excel(file, col_types = tiposDF)
  
  somaVar <- sum(dados[column])
  vari <- append(vari,c(somaVar))
}

vari

file <- paste(path,sep="\\",'Covariância.xls_02082021.xls')
print(paste("Reading ", file))

dados <- read_excel(file, col_types = tiposDF)

somaVar <- sum(dados[column])
vari <- append(vari,c(somaVar))

x <- import(file)
View(x)
```

Thanks everyone!

Comment: Maybe try both `read_xls` and `read_xlsx` and see if either one runs correctly? Per the `read_excel` documentation it tries to determine how the file is encoded and then calls the respective function. Maybe something is causing the wrong function to be called

Comment: @Mako212, thanks, but I tried to simply read the file with 'read_xls' and it retuned `# A tibble: 0 x 0`

Comment: The other thing worth checking is sheet geometry, if your data/headers don't start in `A1`,  try specifying the sheet geometry (i.e. start row and column). If that doesn't do it either, it sounds like an encoding issue with the export from your internal system.

Comment: Even if your data does start in `A1`, you could try adding the `range = cell_limits(c(1, 1), c(NA,  NA))` argument - just to make sure the sheet geometry algorithm isn't misidentifying empty cells as the intended range to read. You can change `c(1, 1)` to whatever row/column index your header is in.

Comment: Hi, @Mako212! Each XLS file has a table that starts at A1 with headers. The one I use in the sum is the column E (from E2 to E10000+). I included the argumetn you suggested, but it didn't make an difference.

Comment: I might have an encoding issue with the export from my internal system. Would it be possible to have an issue that affects all R packages that does not affect Python? Because the analogous argument there does work in the same circunstances.

Comment: I guess one other thing to check is that you have the latest version of `readxl` in `sessionInfo()` - it should be `1.3.1`.

Comment: It is `1.3.1` ... Is there a package that would allow me to change the file extension from XLS to something excel WITHOUT corrupting it? I tried converting a XLS file to XLSX or CSV using `file.rename()` but it didn't work out (even after opening the file, which makes it work fine in my script).

Comment: Are you getting your error message on the call of `read_excel(file, col_types = tiposDF)`? If you just run that line, is that what's generating the error?

Comment: Assuming the above is  true, can you provide a copy of a file that reproduces the error?

Comment: No. It happens during the `sum()` command

Comment: So, @Mako212, I created an incomplete solution. I wrote a VBS and a BAT files that convert all XLS files in the folder to XLSX. This makes the files readable for the R script (don't ask me how). 

Now what I need is to include in the script: 

(1) Copy the VBA and BAT files into the folder I want to run the R script; 
(2) Run the BAT file (it will make the VBS file to run as well); 
(3) Customize the read_excel to read only the XLSX files (it is trying to read both XLS and XLSX files, and even the BAT and VBS); and finally 
(4) Delete the XLS files from the folder.